# Why is IIS Express sending 426 Upgrade Required errors for requests to one my .Web projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have an asp.net application. It has 7 .Web projects, each running on a different port.

I am able to access the APIs and web page for each .Web project except for one: DemandService.Web.

For this particular .Web project, I cannot receive any valid response. The response code is always HTTP 426 Upgrade Required, and this response is sent with the following Headers: server →WebSocket++/0.3.0-alpha4.

Further, this .Web project no longer appears in IIS Express list of running sites.

I have re-GETed my application and have restarted my computer. I verified that there are no pending changes in DemandService.Web that are not found in other .Web project. I am unsure what has changed that may cause this.

Any ideas? Can I reset my IIS Express configuration somehow?

[image][image][image]

**EDIT**

I uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Express 10.0. Now IIS Express indeed starts my .Web project and I can see it running. However, instead of using the port 9005 specified in the project properties, it runs the project on 44322 and is otherwise working.

**Why is IIS Express switching the port on me? Seems like there is some conflict with port 9005 configuration. Is there a vhost directory I should re-configure?**

Comment: Are you sure that the project accepts http connection. 426 error says that the server refuse process the current protocol but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different protocol.

Comment: That is a reasonable question. I have verified that the project URL in Properties -> Web is http://localhost:9005/. I have also unloaded the project and verified the .csproj file has the following properties:

``    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />``

Comment: That header does not come from IIS Express at all. You will have to check further what is running on your machine and generates such responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, the fact that the protocol being used on port 9005 was WebSockets was an indication that the response wasn't coming from IIS Express and therefore I could assume that it wasn't a project or IIS Express configuration problem.

Running `netstat -a -b` shows all the applications using a port on my computer. I examined which process was using port 9005 and the application was CiscoVideoGuardMonitor.exe.

This software is StreamingDRM software that comes with DirectTV player. I installed this last week to watch a basketball game.

Uninstalling this software gave me my port back, which allowed IISExpress to start my service properly, and now I am able to access my .Web project.